# Android Studio, Capture FrameLayout View, While Camera is StopPreview()

Tags: android-studio, android-camera, android-framelayout

This is my `CameraView.java` (I got it from [http://blog.rhesoft.com/](http://blog.rhesoft.com/2015/04/02/tutorial-how-to-use-camera-with-android-and-android-studio/))

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{


private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera){
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)
        return;
    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){

    }

    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}}
```

and this is my `MainActivity.java`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Camera mCamera = null;
private CameraView mCameraView = null;
private FrameLayout camera_view;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try{
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        //you can use open(int) to use different cameras
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if(mCamera != null) {
        mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
        camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
    }

    //btn to close the application
    final ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
    final ImageButton capImg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgCapture);
    imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imgClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            capImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    });
    capImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            imgClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            capImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    System.exit(0);
}}
```

and this my `activity_main.xml`.

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgClose"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="98dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgCapture"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
```

Can I capture this FrameLayout preview as image or do some programing with that preview like delete red color? Can you give me some clue?

Comment: Haha, im really really sorry. but can you stop correcting my English >.<. i need the answer of my question T_T. not my English. about the upperCase or lowCase. its automatic by my hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you wish to get the image data that is shown when you stop the preview? If you so you can mCamera.takePicture() method. It takes 3 parameters, all of which are useful callbacks. Here is something I recently did to show you.

```
        btn_Capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (mCamera == null)
                return;
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    }
    });
```

This is my button click listener which is a floating image button (any button will work just fine). The third parameter is a callback that returns an array of pixels that you can convert into a bitmap.

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        preview.removeView(mPreview);
        img_Captured.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    }
};
```

This is the callback which I passed in the takePicture() method. byte[] data is the image that you are trying to get. As you can see I converted it into a bitmap and displayed it to an ImageView after removing the surfaceview (which holds the camera preview). Just a note, the takePicture() method stops the preview automatically so don't stop the preview before taking the photo. You can do it how I did it in the callback. Also, if you want to take another photo, you can start the preview again.

I hope this helps!! Let me know if I left anything out! By the way, it is all documented on the Android Developer site.

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#TaskTakePicture

Comment: Thanks to Mr. Drew. I almost hopeless here. Haha. Thanks so much.